# Amazon prime video not working

Tags: release-hera, firefox

I've recently installed the elementary OS 5.1 Hera, Amazon Prime Videos will not work, they just

Comment: Have you tried with chrome?

Comment: Prime Video has worked for me with Mozilla Firefox on elementary OS. For Firefox-related troubleshooting you might want to consult Mozilla's own Firefox support site: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem, the issue was installing the package using snap, it almost seemed like websites thought I was logging on from a mobile device. When I deleted it and reinstalled using apt it worked fine, this was also  problem with a fps game I installed with snap as well